# Dropdown TopNav Links Dead, Only with "New" Experience

Tags: office-365, navigation, top-link-bar, bug

O365 SharePoint dropdown TopNav links work perfectly well on pages/Libraries using "Classic SharePoint". If those same pages/Libraries are viewed using the "New Experience", then TopNav links stop working...

Confirmed on multiple machines, multiple browsers. Has anyone seen this? Any known workarounds?

Comment: It's a known issue. Click event has a javascript error: TypeError: e.stopPropagation is not a function.

Comment: Crazy - the "New Experience" they're pushing isn't really usable with this bug...

Comment: For reference, this is filed with Microsoft here: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_sharepoint-mso_winother/sharepoint-online-bug-new-experience-breaks-nested/cdcb23ed-2eb0-419e-99ea-f51ffc410477

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We asked the question on the Microsoft forums and got some feedback from an admin. A few weeks later, it seems Microsoft has fixed the bug in their Javascript code. Hopefully the fix is propagated to everyone that uses O365...

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_sharepoint-mso_winother/sharepoint-online-bug-new-experience-breaks-nested/cdcb23ed-2eb0-419e-99ea-f51ffc410477